# Generate 25 psuedo-random strings

Tags: python, random

I have code that is pseudo-randomly generating strings. How can I get my code to output 25 random strings?

```
import random, string

special=['@','!','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','=','+','{','[','}',']',';',':','.','>','<',',','?','/',]

def id_generator(size=25, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + random.choice(special) ):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

count = 0

def create_and_save_pseudorand():
    for count in range(100):
        return id_generator()
        #print(id_generator())

create_and_save_pseudorand()
```

Comment: Note that `return` will *end the function* - did you mean to `yield`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you either want to

```py
return [id_generator() for i in range(25)]
```

or swap the `return` with a `yield` and then use:

```py
for i in create_and_save_pseudorand():
    print i
```

btw: you seem to confuse the length and the number of strings. Which one should be 25?

Comment: Both should be 25. 25 string, 25 chars in length

Answer (score 0):

Your function `create_and_save_pseudorand` currently stops after returning the first randomly generated string. Change `return` to `yield` to fix that. Then you can introduce a `count` parameter to determine the count of random strings that you want to generate.

```
def create_and_save_pseudorand(count):
    for count in range(count):
        yield id_generator()
```

You might then print the result on the console using

```
print(list(create_and_save_pseudorand(25)))
```

Example output:

```
['YAB*MT7CU29IY12QMVLNH4QI9', '1E1445DCN*5K7RZIJNKSIKX10', '53W06LS8NJEAE0X60MFW*ES*W', 'KK8WMRA3DMPRWWYQDG2M0ED0Q', 'ZFLBQ0V04Z*E1PVUF4DG04IJ2', '292VPZA3QDKLQ4UBTKJA3TY3H', 'A77426HK1HNZVMUT883CZABIX', 'I2M4I0IO9GRLNVAH9BWV52AYJ', '*VUU3DGHN79SG5XPELHCKSG29', '*KWM2BUPGIL4OV3TUZ7614OAT', '29JZ*Y59*O2SPL7CWL9BB3*5V', 'IVZ0MK0HPIVCJG039Y9GTM*ZH', 'ZF2QSL5VXYW6B4*FOE4KRL4LW', 'ZOK*Z508DD1JE5UYHLGGKORKS', 'L2XIBU8J3IMZO9Y2GFLQSB3W7', 'PA6ZJGXS4G96FDA771143TOMM', '2ZHK13LVZZQ878L1OR2LQ3TGV', 'QGYR2WNJ58GPD0*54CHI6AKAR', 'TKPBD27HQ0TZFFZCVMIDAYJX4', 'G7HH9YSZ4P3ETRGY9REB90WDC', 'G3PTXR376AGJHX4V5V4NRLL30', 'XHM1J0A5Z48*58RFVH9W3Z5*O', 'XHG8VGNF*YA4GBX1SBE*DVGKV', '39YNN1X719N*WZ9VBUPLTVC5P', 'XYMJ57DH*3WX589J9ZENGFP0O']
```

Comment: What about output to a webpage?

Comment: @CodeTalk what about it?

Comment: How can i? This outputs just (1) value to a webpage